# Power series with $x^{4n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I'm new to this Forum. 
I do not find an approach to solve the following problem (from 
the book "Herbert Wallner, Aufgabensammlung Mathematik Band 1",
so this is not a homework question):

For which $x\in\mathbb{R}$ does the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{4n}}{(2+3x^{4})^{n+1}}$$ converge.

According to the book the solution is: For $x\in\Bbb{R}$.

I think at first I have to write the series in the form $\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty}a_n(x-x_0)^n$, so that I can apply the other methods for power series examination (radius of convergence etc), but I do not know how.

Comment: If you are interested your series converges to a rational function $$\frac{x^4}{2(1-x^4)(2-3x^4)}$$

Comment: Is there any way to solve this problem using the cauchy-hadamard theorem or other methods for examining the radius of convergence since this problem is in the power series chapter of the mentioned book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Note that

$$0\le \frac{x^{4n}}{(2+3x^{4})^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{2+3x^4}\left(\frac{x^4}{2+3x^4} \right)^n< \frac{1}{2+3x^4}\frac{1}{3^n}\le \frac{1}{2\cdot3^n}$$

$\forall x\in \mathbb{R},\forall n\in \mathbb{N}.$

Comment: Thus the fraction sequence is a zero sequence, but this does not proof that the series converges, or what do you mean?

Comment: The series converges for any $x$ since all terms are nonnegative and $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{4n}}{(2+3x^{4})^{n+1}}\le \frac12 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^n},$$ with the second series convergent.

Comment: Ah, you mean according to the direct comparison test, right?

Comment: Yes, I mean that.